# CSS simple loading animation is not iterating

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a simple CSS based loading animation that should iterate with `infinite`. However, the animation only runs once and stops. I'm surely missing something trivial but can't spot the error.

A related question, to shorten the CSS, can I join all the vendor specific selectors into one block, as in the following example?

```
@keyframes loading-dots,
@-webkit-keyframes loading-dots,
@-[other vendors...]
 {
  0%,
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a snippet:

```css
.loading-dots span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 9px;
  width: 9px;
  background: #abb3b8;
  -webkit-animation: loading-dots 0.8s infinite;
  -moz-animation: loading-dots 0.8s infinite;
  -ms-animation: loading-dots 0.8s infinite;
  animation: loading-dots 0.8s infinite;
}

.loading-dots span:nth-child(2) {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.loading-dots span:nth-child(3) {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes loading-dots {
  0%,
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading-dots {
  0%,
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes loading-dots {
  0%,
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes loading-dots {
  0%,
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-dots">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you just want to add in a frame where they all disappear.  Right now they just stay put and blink as they re-render.

Comment: Thanks @jmargolisvt, I think you are correct, if I set a 90% keyframe than it iterates. The first square can remain put, I want the second and third to blink. The keyframe change plus some messing around with delay should give me the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using opacity with any visibility animation check the code below with opacity .. because animating `visibility` or `display` is not a good idea as they are a 1/0 values that can't be animated

```css
    .loading-dots span {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity:0;
  height: 9px;
  width: 9px;
  background: #abb3b8;
  -webkit-animation: loading-dots 0.8s infinite;
  -moz-animation: loading-dots 0.8s infinite;
  -ms-animation: loading-dots 0.8s infinite;
  animation: loading-dots 0.8s infinite;
}

.loading-dots span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.loading-dots span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes loading-dots {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading-dots {
  0% {
   opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes loading-dots {
  0%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes loading-dots {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  },
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-dots">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @AmrLabib. Although `visibility` can be toggle within an animation I think using `opacity` renders a more visually pleasing solution.